# iPad modal view's rect within the main window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am presenting a modal view (with UIModalPresentationFormSheet) on top of a UISplitViewController. I want to get the exact rect that the modal view will take relative to the UISplitViewController (which is basically the whole window). i.e. the modal view is at x,y coordinate and the size. 
How would I find this? I looked at UIView's "convertRect:fromView:" method, but couldn't figure out what combination would work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[splitView convertRect:modallyPresentedVC.view.bounds fromView:modallyPresentedVC.view]` should do the trick. Make sure to call it in the completion block of the presentation (after all animation has finished).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to give some strange results. I tried this: [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion: ^{ CGRect clippedRect = [split.view convertRect: childController.view.bounds  toView: childController.view];
}]; But it gives some strange coordinates: {{-242, -128}, {540, 576}}

Comment: For this to work correctly, you need to present like so: `[split presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:...]`. Otherwise, there is no superview chain and you get incorrect results. You can still calculate it, but it would be more complex.